# Sending data from JS file to HTML page

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express

I am new to NodeJS. Here is the simple program to send data back and forth from HTML to NodeJS files. My index.html contains a form and div to display the reply received back from server.js:

```
<html>
<body>

    <form action = "http://127.0.0.1:8000/process_post" method = "POST">
        First Name: <input type = "text" name = "first_name">  <br>
        Last Name: <input type = "text" name = "last_name">  <br>
        <input type = "submit" value = "Submit">
    </form>
    <div><%= name %></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Below is the code for server.js:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var urlencodedParser = bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false })
app.use(urlencodedParser);

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});

app.post('/process_post', function (req, res) {
    var name = req.body.first_name+ ' ' + req.body.last_name;   //to send back to HTML
    console.log(name);
    res.send(name);
 });

var server = app.listen(8000);
```

How to update the name in HTML page with the value of name in JS program, each time the form is submitted?

Answer (score 0):

You can use AJAX (fetch or Axios for example). 
Create an event listener on your submit input with a function like this:

```js
axios.post('/process_post', {
    first_name: 'Fred',
    last_name: 'Flintstone'
  })
  .then(response => {
    document.querySelector('div').textContent = response;
  })
  .catch(error => {
    console.log(error);
  });
```